# Counting and merging features based on attribute field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, fields-attributes, grouping, aggregate

I have a shapefile with a number of features, each with a field called `"region"`. I want to count the number of features corresponding to each region. Outputting a shapefile with *one feature per region*, and new field called `"count"`. E.G. Latin America : 13, Europe : 5, Asia : 14 etc. How can achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a new field with the expression `count($id,group_by:="continent")`
2. **Dissolve** the layer by `"continent"` field
3. *Optional: remove the fields which are no longer valid or you dont need*
4. Run **Split Vector Layer** and choose `"continent"` as your `UID` field and `shp` as `file type`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Menu Pocessing / Toolbox / Aggregate` ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=aggregate#aggregate)). For `group by expression` use the`region` field.

To get the necessary values in the attribute table, set the `region` field to `first_value` and create a new field (highlighted with red frame in the screenshot) with `Source Expression` corresponding to your `region` field and the `Aggregate Function` set to `count`. Be sure the field has a corresponding field type and length, see screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution implies the usage of a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'grid_test'* with its attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to *count the number of features corresponding to each region*.

```sql
SELECT
    geometry,
    COUNT() AS "count"
FROM
    "grid_test"
GROUP BY
    "region"
```

[image: result1]

*P.S.* On the last image original polygons with modified transparency were also visualized.

Application of the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group_concat/) is optional, but can be used to aggregate the features' ids.

A new query will look like

```sql
SELECT
    geometry,
    COUNT() AS "count",
    GROUP_CONCAT("id") AS "ids"
FROM
    "grid_test"
GROUP BY
    "region"
```

And the new output will be the following

[image: result2]